# Very basic derived functor question

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, derived-functors

This my first ever exposure to the notion of having "enough injectives" and to derived functors in general. I am looking at this Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_functor#Construction_and_first_properties), speifically the 'Construction and first properties' section. For simplicity just assume we're in an Abelian category and the class of morphisms is all the monomorphisms. Let  $X$ be an object in the category $\mathcal{C}$. How do we know that there must exist an exact sequence, 
$$ 0 \longrightarrow X \longrightarrow I^{0} \longrightarrow I^{1} \longrightarrow I^{2} \longrightarrow \cdots ,$$
where the $I^{i}$ objectives are injective objects?
I can see how knowing that every object has a monomorphism from it to some injective object would give you exactness at the first term (trivially), but then how do you get exactness for further terms?

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia page you refer to does not seem to give the whole construction, which is the following.

[image]

One starts with a monomorphism $\iota\colon X\rightarrowtail I^0$ to an injective object. Then, to obtain an exact sequence, we want to factor through the cokernel of $\iota$, so we take the canonical epimorphism $\epsilon^0\colon I^0 \twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{coker} \iota$ and compose it with a monomorphism $\iota^1\colon \operatorname{coker} \iota \rightarrowtail I^1$, which exists because we have enough injectives.

Inductively, the differential $d^n\colon I^n \to I^{n+1}$ is the composition $\iota^{n+1}\circ\epsilon^n$ of the canonical epimorphism $\epsilon^n\colon I^n \twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{coker} \iota^n$ and a monomorphism $\iota^{n+1}\colon \operatorname{coker} \iota^n\rightarrowtail I^{n+1}$.

You should be able to prove yourself that the resulting sequence is exact (e.g. by a diagram chase).